# Searching through a txt file and printing next word of a string

Tags: windows, script, batch-file

I have a batch script which will print the entire line of search string into a text file.

```
   for %%i in (configure.txt) do (
   FINDSTR /C:"Widget Name=" %%i >> output.txt
   )
```

Here is how my Configure.txt file will look like:

```
   <Widget Name="example_1_new" Type="IFC"/>
   <Property Name="exmaple_2_old"/>
   <Content>
   <Widget Name="example_3_new"/>
   <Widget Name="example_4_old"/>
   <Widget Name="exmaple_1_new"/>
   </Content>
```

I want to print the next word(example1) after the "Widget Name="(Search String) and also find the duplicates of the word(Example1) and print its count next to it,So that my output should be like:

```
   example_1_new 2
```

Can someone let me know how to do this? 
Please note the configure.txt has around 1000 lines of data like above. I just gave an example.

Comment: So my solution isn't one anymore. If you installed [cigwin](https://www.cygwin.com/install.html), You could do quick `unix ` style programs by using [tag:awk]. Here is very good reference, step by step: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

Comment: I will try awk for my next one , I need to do it in batch now for my above mentioned task. Please let me know your suggestions for the above if you are good at batch scripting @Chomel

Comment: Sorry I'm not. Good luck here!

Comment: [My updated script](http://superuser.com/a/1095041/376602) works however there is an anagram-like typo in your data: ex**am**ple_1 versus ex**ma**ple_1

Answer (score 2):

Next *commented* code snippet should do the job:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem delete auxiliary variables
for /F %%G in ('set ___ 2^>NUL') do set "%%G=" 

rem count up number of occurrences 
for /F tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%G in ('
    FINDSTR /C:"Widget Name=" "configure.txt"
  ') do set /A "___%%G+=1"

rem subtract 1 to get number of duplicates
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G in ('set ___ 2^>NUL') do set /A "%%G-=1"

REM output: does dot work if your data contains _ underscore
REM for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=_=" %%G in ('set ___ 2^>NUL') do echo %%G %%H

rem alternative output
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G in ('set ___ 2^>NUL') do (
  set "_auxvarname=%%G"
  call set "_auxvarname=%%_auxvarname:~3%%"
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo !_auxvarname! %%H
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

To create output file, change last lines as follows:

```
rem alternative output
> output.txt (
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G in ('set ___ 2^>NUL') do (
      set "_auxvarname=%%G"
      call set "_auxvarname=%%_auxvarname:~3%%"
      SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo !_auxvarname! %%H
      ENDLOCAL
    )
)
```

**Output** with data merged from *original* question and from *updated* one:

```
==> type "configure.txt"
<Widget Name="example1"/>
<Property Name="exmaple2"/>
<Content Name="example3"/>
<Widget Name="example4"/>
<Widget Name="example1"/>
<Widget Name="example_1_new" Type="IFC"/>
<Property Name="exmaple_2_old"/>
<Content>
<Widget Name="example_3_new"/>
<Widget Name="example_4_old"/>
<Widget Name="exmaple_1_new"/>
</Content>

==> D:\bat\SU\1094786.bat
example1 1
example4 0
example_1_new 0
example_3_new 0
example_4_old 0
exmaple_1_new 0
```

Comment: It just prints all the Widget Names, even if it is seen twice it is printed once in the output file. My input file widget name has "example_1" "example_2" etc.. Is the _ affecting the above code output in anyway? @josefZ

Comment: I have edited my inputs again for your clarity.. Please check it.

Comment: I am getting output like this   :                                                                       example_1_new                                                                                               example_3_new                                                                                             example_4_old

Comment: I just need to print the duplicated widget names and the count which says how many times it had occured in the text file. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Great.... works nice. :) Few things I dont understand in the script, Can you please give me some explanation @Josefz

Comment: I have a folder named **Resource** inside which I have sub-folders(has txt files) and also few .txt files in the Resource folder.. I have the string "Widget name=" in all the txt files. I want to compare each and every widget name to all the widget names in other text files and find the duplicates. How can i modify the above to do it..Its like example_1_new should be compared to all other widget names (like example_2_new or whatever) in all text files inside the **Resource** folder. I tried with few but doesn't work.. Can you help me.. @Josefz